# Теряется сессия при редиректе на мобильных устройствах

Tags: php

Имеется сайт с несколькими PHP файлами. При лог-ине пользователя в сессию записывается токен. 
Проблема состоит в том, что когда происходит редирект на другую страницу(на этом же домене, страница с точно таким же адресом), то токен этот теряется(причем только на мобильных устройствах). 
Проблема была бы более ясна, но c помощью токена я тяну данные из API, и часть из этих функций получают этот токен, а другая - нет(передаю токен в них через $_SESSION['token']).
Так же сессия не видна только при вызове функцию из одного из множества файлов.

UPD. Проблемы наблюдаются только на IOS

Comment: Не вызывается `session_start()`. Или вызывается, но уже после того, как был осуществлен вывод данных. Включайте  логи, смотрите ошибки

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov В том то и дело что вызывается. Проблема проявляется исключительно на IOS устройствах

Comment: Используйте кукы, просто пердавайте их на все поддомены и отлавливайте)